# English dates to Russian with PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, localization, multilingual

I am building a multilingual site that will be displayed in both English and Russian. Everything in terms of translation is working very well, with the exception of dates.

As I understand it, PHP's `strtotime()` function is strictly for english dates as it says in the official docs "[Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)."

I have already tried using `setlocale( LC_TIME, 'ru_RU', 'russian' );` and then `strftime()` but it just keeps returning the unix `January 1970` date.

What I am attempting to do is get the day name (i.e. Wednesday) from a date and display it. Normally, with an english date, I would just do it like `$this->day = date('l', strtotime( $date ));` but because I am trying to do it with both English and Russian I am doing it like so `$this->day = strftime("%A", strtotime($date) );`

My date is formatted in words like "**October 13, 2015**" which I'm assuming is part of the problem because the Russian translation for "October" is "Октябрь" So the end result that I end up trying to parse is "Октябрь 13, 2015" which always returns "Thursday" when in fact October 13 is Tuesday.

Here is everything I am doing to parse the date:

```
$this->month_arr = array();

// Loop through $event_dates array created above
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'ru') {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8', 'rus_RUS.1251', 'rus', 'russian');
}

foreach($this->event_dates as $date => $time) {

    // Create the unix timestamp to parse with PHP
    $unix_date = strtotime($date);
    $this->month = strftime("%B", $unix_date);
    $this->day = strftime("%A", $unix_date);
    $this->year = strftime("%G", $unix_date);

    // Create new array with date info
    $this->month_arr[$this->month][] = $this->day; // Day of week
    $this->month_arr[$this->month][] = $date; // Full textual date
    $this->month_arr[$this->month][] = $this->year; // 4 Digit Year
    $this->month_arr[$this->month][] = $time; // Start/end time array
}
```

This parses the english representation of the date perfectly, but everything else seems to get messed up. As a temporary fall back, I have removed the day of the week from the final display and am just stripping "October" or "Октябрь" from the initial date string and displaying that, but this is not what the client is expecting.

I have also tried this format: `strftime('%B %e, %Y', $unix_date);` in hopes that matching the `strftime()` format with the way the date is originally displayed would work, but that gave me the same end result.

P.S. I am running this all on my localhost MAMP server. The production/staging servers are running on nginx.

**EDIT:** This is a WordPress website and the date is being created via the '[Advanced Custom Fields Pro](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)' plugin. The plugin doesn't allow users to save the date as a timestamp. I have already tried using WP's built in `date_i18n($format, $unix_timestamp);` function with no luck.

**EDIT  x2:** I am currently doing something like this:

```
// Russian Months
$ru_months = array( 'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь' );

// English Months
$en_months = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );

// Get date string from ACF
$date_arr = explode(" ", get_sub_field('date'));

// Get the month name
$month = $date_arr[0];

// Get the array index of the month name
$month_index = array_search($month, $en_months);    

// Piece together new date string in Russian translation
$date = $ru_months[$month_index] . " " . $day . ", " . $year;
```

Which works for now, but I want to translate the day name as well. For example, **Tuesday October 13, 2015** and this method doesn't provide a solid way of doing that.

Comment: Thanks @PaulCrovella, I'll look into it.

Comment: Just for context, is there a reason the dates are stored as formatted strings rather than timestamps ? Can you provide a few samples of what is inside `$this->event_dates` as to allow to test on it ?

Comment: I will also point out that `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, which has a timestamp equal to `0 == null == false`, was a thursday.

Comment: @spenibus The date is coming through as a string because it is being created using the 'Advanced Custom Fields Pro' WordPress plugin, which does not allow you to save your date as a timestamp. I have modified my question to give a better understanding of the environment.

Comment: The dates are coming from some form of storage ? They are stored in either language ? They were saved from an ACF date picker ?

Comment: Yes. They are being stored via a MySQL database but are being created using the Advanced Custom Fields WordPress plugin. The plugin doesn't allow it to be saved in the form of a timestamp, but rather in `10/13/2015` or `October 13, 2015` format.

Comment: I see in the ACF docs that the date picker has options for a display format and a save format. Are they both set to the same value ?

Comment: No, they are not. Are you suggesting they should be stored and displayed the same way?

Comment: Quite the contrary. What are the formats ?

Comment: Storage format: `m/d/Y` Display Format: `F j, Y`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91763/discussion-between-spenibus-and-ty-bailey).

Comment: You should be able to access the value with the storage format, which could easily be parsed using the `DateTime` class: `$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $dateString);`. It seems odd you would work on the display value.

Comment: Would the `DateTime()` class be able to parse international dates? Like, would `Октябрь 13, 2015` be parsed properly and spit out `Tuesday` rather than `Thursday`?

Comment: Nothing in the docs seems to indicate this is possible. If you insist on `F j, Y` I'll just provide an answer that uses that then. Your current method is on the right track considering the circumstances. I'm assuming there is no variation of uppercase/lowercase of the month name, it's always written the same as seen in your current solution ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see three options here.

---

1. **Write your own parser.**

You can always write PHP code to convert the date yourself.
It is dirty, it is brute force, but it is straight forward.

```php
function add_weekday( $date ) {
   $ru_weekdays = array( 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Воскресенье' );
   $en_weekdays = array( 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday' );
   $ru_months = array( 'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь' );
   $en_months = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );
   $en_date = str_replace( $ru_months, $en_months, $date );
   $weekdays = $en_date === $date ? $en_weekdays : $ru_weekdays;
   // $wday = strptime( $en_date, '%B %e, %Y' );       // Linux/Mac
   // return $weekdays[ $wday['tm_wday']-1 ]." $date"; // Linux/Mac
   return $weekdays[ DateTime::createFromFormat( 'M j, Y', $en_date )->format( 'N' )-1 ]." $date"; // PHP 5.3+
}
echo add_weekday( 'Октябрь 13, 2015' ); // Вторник Октябрь 13, 2015
echo add_weekday( 'October 13, 2015' ); // Tuesday October 13, 2015
```

---

2. **Use a library.**

For example, [PECL intl module](https://pecl.php.net/package/intl) has an [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php):

```php
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter( 'ru', IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::NONE );
$datetime = $formatter->parse( "13 октября 2015 r." );
$weekday = $datetime->format( 'l' ); // 'Tuesday'
```

However intl is very picky; the date string must match its *exact* format:
No uppercase, no oктябр**ь**, date must be before month, and it must ends with "r.".

Not flexible enough to worth the trouble, if you ask me.

---

3. **[Ask](http://sqlfiddle.com/) an *enterprise* database.**

I love [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx). Look:

```sql
SELECT datename( dw, Try_Parse( N'Октябрь 13, 2015' AS date USING 'Ru-RU' ) );
-- 'Tuesday', if default language is English

SET LANGUAGE 'Russian';
SELECT datename( dw, Try_Parse( N'Октябрь 13, 2015' AS date ) );
-- 'вторник'
```

Or [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm), also gets the job done:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( 'Октябрь 13, 2015', 'MON DD, YYYY', 'nls_date_language = Russian' )
   , 'DAY', 'nls_date_language = Russian' ) FROM DUAL;
-- 'ВТОРНИК'

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'RUSSIAN';
SELECT TO_CHAR( TO_DATE( 'Октябрь 13, 2015', 'MON DD, YYYY' ), 'DAY' ) FROM DUAL;
-- 'ВТОРНИК'
```

You don't need any i18n modules - they have them built-in.

> MySQL cannot parse international date - just like PHP.

I know most common configs do not give you SQL Server or Oracle, but they are free, and you don't need to use them as your main database.
Once you got them setup and connected, many datetime i18n problems can be solved with a single query.

But be careful.  This is exactly how I [fell in love](http://www.noelherrick.com/blog/mysql-vs-sql-server) with SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I am going to work on writing my own parser and hope it works out. If you have any resources/tips/tricks for doing that, I'd love to hear/see them.

Comment: @TyBailey I added php code that prepend Russian/English weekday to your date string - it varies a bit by your platform and/or php version. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: There is enough information here for me to put together my own parser. I appreciate the time you took to put this detailed answer together, so you win my bounty. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), i.e.:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
$ruDate = 'Октябрь 13, 2015';
$enDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j, Y', ruMonthsToEn($ruDate));
echo  $enDate->format('l, F, j, Y');
//Tuesday, October, 13, 2015
echo  $enDate->getTimestamp();
//1444764954

function ruMonthsToEn($date){
    $ruMonths = array( 'Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь' );
    $enMonths = array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' );
    return str_replace($ruMonths, $enMonths, $date);
}
```

Comment: Note: the input format seems to be `F j, Y`. Impeccable otherwise. That timestamp can go straight to [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php).

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct: `strtotime()` will only parse *english* strings into integers. You might have missed that when the function cannot make a translation, it returns a boolean false:

```
$date = "October 13, 2015";
$rudate = "октября 13, 2015";
var_dump(strtotime( $date )); //outputs int(1444687200)
var_dump(strtotime( $rudate )); //ouputs bool(false)
```

When you try to call `date()` or `strftime()` with a boolean value, PHP for whatever reason decides to default to a certain date which happens to be a Thursday.

```
var_dump(date('l', false)); //outputs string(8) "Thursday"
var_dump(strftime("%A", false)); //outputs string(8) "Thursday"
```

As your data is already stored, you must mutate it before being able to process it with existing PHP functions. Since you only have to translate Russian to English, the change is reasonably painless:

```
//You should, of course, add the other months in.
function dateToEnglish($str)
{
    $str = str_replace('января', 'January', $str);
    //...
    $str = str_replace('октября', 'October', $str);
    //...
    $str = str_replace('Декабрь', 'December', $str);

    return $str;
}

var_dump(strtotime(dateToEnglish($rudate))); //outputs int(1444687200)
```

You can use this to parse the date into english before further processing:

```
foreach($this->event_dates as $date => $time) {

    // Create the unix timestamp to parse with PHP
    $unix_date = strtotime(dateToEnglish($date));
    // ...
}
```

---

Each language you want to support will need to be added in manually, which is a *major* downside to this strategy. However, your approach to this problem has some serious [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) by the way you are working with strings instead of timestamps.

In the future, you should store your dates as timestamps (see [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)) as they are language agnostic and would not require this extra step of processing.

Comment: Please see my updated question. I cannot save the date as a timestamp as it is being generated through a WP plugin which does not allow that.